# How do i show a customer name when they login to woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I was wondering if anyone can help with the above issue, I somehow need the Account link at the top of the page to display the customers name when logged in, but in all honesty know very little in the way of coding php or js. i'm mostly visual changes, layouts and upkeep of products on here and am way out of my depth when it comes to figuring out how to do something like this.

The site is https://roofin.co.uk/ and I need to change this to make it display the name any help would be hugely appreciated

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="user-acc">
                <a class="acc-link" href="https://roofin.co.uk/my-account-2/">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                <span class="my-acc">My Account</span>
                <span class="sign-in">Sign in / Register</span>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
       <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="user-acc">
                <a class="acc-link" href="https://roofin.co.uk/my-account-2/">
                  <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                  <?php 
                  if(!is_user_logged_in())
                  {
                  ?>
                    <span class="my-acc">My Account</span>
                    <span class="sign-in">Sign in / Register</span>
                  <?php 
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                  ?>
                      <span class="my-acc"><?php echo $current_user->display_name; ?></span>
                  <?php
                  }
                  ?>
                </a>
            </div>
       </div>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the following line of code:

```
if( $current_user = wp_get_current_user() ) echo $current_user->display_name;
```

It will display the current user display name only when it's logged in.

Comment: You are one of the finest one in this community. Having the reputation [75K], this comment does not suites you. I am highly obliged that you mentioned my name in your comment. I believ that it will be more fair if you leave that choosing option to the user only.

Comment: I dont think that he done anything wrong. The answer given by you and me are same. What differs is that I gave him as answer which he can just copy and paste.He mentioned that he is not a WordPress guy so I did that to help him out and it helps. You are quite correct that reputation doesnot matter otherwise he will choose you. Hope everyone should have chance play the game, and moderator will check the fair part.

Comment: Do I need to find any meaning of it?